# Why the main page of apache points to Virtual Host

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I've configured two Virtual Hosts using a single IP and following the documentation. Here the conf:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server host1.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1019)
         port 80 namevhost host1.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1019)
         port 80 namevhost host2.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1024)
```

If I point my browser to `host1.example.com` or `host2.example.com`, I can see the correct corresponding page. If I point to the server name `server.example.com`, I see the `host1.example.com` index.html, and not the index.html in the corresponding DocumentRoot (`/var/www/html`).
Is this the correct behaviour?

Comment: show us your actual apache configuration, I'm not sure what you have given us.

Comment: That was the output of `httpd -S`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the behavior changes when you enable virtual hosts from serving the global DocumentRoot directory to serve the first defined virtual host.

You should set a first virtual host (that appears in your configuration) to serve /var/www/html and then one for host1 and another for host2.

Comment: Makes sense. And what if I would not use the DocumentRoot /var/www/html directory? Should I comment it in the httpd.conf?